# Apache Superset font fomatting for specific text in a table

Tags: visualization, apache-superset

Is it possible to have a font formatting for specific text in a table row.

For e.g if the output for my SQL query is one column with rows of text is it possible to highlight percentage values in the text as below.

[Attendance Insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHe0b.png)

We have tried formatting using CSS options but it applies to the complete sentence however we want to highlight only the percentages here.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can not achieve that by css styling in table chart. I would suggest using handlebars chart where you can have more control, create your own table and it will be easier to style some specific fields like attendance once you wrap them in `span` tag